# Plotly.js: wrong click when I use plotly_click event [JS]

Tags: javascript, plotly

I implemented a javascript script that creates a graph using Plotly, via websockets.

Here the script:

```
var modalCount = 0;

function graphTest(fio2) {

    var myPlot = document.getElementById('graphFiO2');

    var time = new Date();
    var update = {
        x: [[time]],
        y: [[fio2]]
    }

    myPlot.on('plotly_click', function(){
        modalCount++;
        console.log(modalCount);
    });

    Plotly.extendTraces('graphFiO2', update, [0]);
```

modalCount instead of increasing with each click, it increases a lot based on how much data I received from the websockets, why?

EDIT:

modalCount increases in the wrong way, example: I want that modalCount increase for every click event:
 First click - modalCount = 1, Second click - modalCount = 2 ..

What happens instead: First click - modalCount = 10, second click = modalCount =27 (numbers nosense)

Comment: `it increases a lot`. What is `lot`?

Comment: modalCount increases in the wrong way, example: I want that modalCount increase for every click event: First click - modalCount = 1, Second click - modalCount = 2 ...   what happens instead: First click - modalCount = 10, second click = modalCount =27 (numbers nosense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, each update from the websocket you call `graphTest`?  Well, you are then adding a new click handler on each update.  So, every click is calling **all these handlers** increasing your count in an unexpected way.  You should refactor your code so that click handler is only bound once.  Pseudo-code below:

```
  var modalCount = 0,
      myPlot = document.getElementById('graphFiO2');

  Plotly.newPlot('graphFiO2', initialData, {});

  myPlot.on('plotly_click', function() {
    modalCount++;
    console.log(modalCount);
  });

  function graphTest(fio2) {

      var time = new Date();
      var update = {
        x: [
          [time]
        ],
        y: [
          [fio2]
        ]
      }

      Plotly.extendTraces('graphFiO2', update, [0]);    
  }
```